# cannot show result from an instance function in haskell

Tags: class, haskell, show, instances

```
class (Eq k, Ord k, Show k) => KEY k where
  keyBuild    :: NumId -> NumId -> NumId  -> k
  keyDummy    :: k
  keyFromList :: [NumId] -> k
  -- keyGenerate :: (DATAPOOL p) => p -> Int -> [k]  -- p = Pool k e s


newtype PrimaryKey = PK (NumId, NumId, NumId) deriving (Eq, Ord, Show) 

instance KEY PrimaryKey where
  keyBuild k0 k1 k2 = PK (k0,k1,k2)
  keyDummy          = PK (0,0,0)
  keyFromList is    = keyFromList (take 3 (is ++ (replicate 3 0)))
  keyGenerate p cnt = let
                        ks = keys p
                        pks = map (\l ->  keyFromList (randomize l))                   (replicate cnt 3)
                      in pks
```

in ghci I do

```
let k1 = keyBuild 1 2 3
let k2 = PK (1,2,3)
k1 == k2 
True
k2
PK (1,2,3)
```

and get True and the value of k2 as expected, but

```
k1
231:1: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘it’
      prevents the constraint ‘(KEY a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instance exist:
        instance [safe] KEY PrimaryKey -- Defined at Work
```

Expected PK(1,2,3)
PrimaryKey has deriving (Eq, Ord, Show) so what have I done wrong or missed?

Comment: NumId = Int in the testing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not given `k1` a fixed type. Because `keyBuild` can construct a key of *any* type with the right instance, it has the polymorphic type `k1 :: KEY k => k`. That's nice because you can then compare `k1` to keys of different concrete types... in your case, you've tried it with `k2 :: PrimaryKey`, but you could just as well do `k1 == k3` with `k3 :: SomeOtherKeyType`, provided `SomeOtherKeyType` is also an instance of the `KEY` class – in that case, `k1` would simply also “take over” the type `SomeOtherKeyType`.

The flip side is that `k1` has no *particular* type. It may in fact be *any* applicable type, but how is the compiler supposed to know which you want? When using `==` it must be the same type on both sides, so there it's sufficient to have a concrete type on one side, but all by itself `k1` is ambiguous.

It so happens that in your module there is only one instance that matches, namely `KEY PrimaryKey` but in general there would be many (or zero!) such instances. It would be strange if the compiler just picked one arbitrarily, wouldn't it?

So if you want to show `k1`, you need to manually pick one type. Easy enough to do, just add a local signature:

```
*Main> let k1 = keyBuild 1 2 3
*Main> :t k1
k1 :: KEY k => k
*Main> k1 :: PrimaryKey
PK (1,2,3)
```